# pdfkit - is there a way to change the HTML before converting it to pdf?

Tags: python, python-requests, pdfkit

I'm using the module python pdfkit: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pdfkit

The page I want to convert to pdf has a modal window that covers the content I need to save in pdf, I'm accessing via python requests. What I need to do is close the modal and then call the pdfkit.from-url method: `pdfkit.from_url('http://the_page.com', 'out.pdf', options={'cookie': s.cookies.items()})`

But I do not know if it is possible to remove the modal using requests. And I do not want to use selenium!

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Just a general recommendation, could you fetch the HTML separately via URLLib (or something like that), edit out the modal, and then use `pdfkit.from_string(HtmlString, 'out.pdf')`? Alternatively, as it seems like PDFKit relies on WebKit for creating a mock-up rendering before saving, you might just be able to use `.replace(...)` or something of that nature to insert a `style='display:none;'` on the modal element. For reference, though, I have no experience with PDFKit, so these are just shots in the dark.

Comment: It works but not the way I wanted it, it loses the css and the images of the page and generates a pdf only with the non-external css. This happens because from_string only uses the text of the page and not its resources, since from_url takes everything!

Comment: I was randomly surfing stack overflow, and then I came across a question that reminded me of your problem. You may be able to use [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) for this. I am not sure if that can be done without Selenium, but it might be worth exploring.

Comment: there are a number of ways to do this... insert the external css into the htmlstring; use beautifulsoup to remove the modal window; insert css that makes the window invisible

Answer (score 1):

`pdfkit` has the open to read from an html file. So you could save the html locally, make any edits, and then write to a pdf file.

```
pdfkit.from_file(['file1.html', 'file2.html'], 'out.pdf')
```

or

```
with open('file.html') as f:
    pdfkit.from_file(f, 'out.pdf')
```